# Spring ConditionalOnProperty - understanding the "havingValue" property?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The javadoc for `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty` is like below -

```
public abstract java.lang.String havingValue 
The string representation of the expected value for the properties. 
If not specified, the property must not be equal to false.

Returns:
the expected value

Default:
"
```

What i don't understand in the above is `If not specified, the property must not be equal to false.`
If the property is not specified at all, then how can it be false (or true or xyz).

From the [ConditionalOnProperty api](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) doc - this part is clear.

```
If the property is not contained in the Environment at all, the matchIfMissing() attribute is consulted. By default missing attributes do not match.
```

Comment: I thing specified refers to “havingValue” - “The havingValue() attribute can be used to specify the value that the property should have” - from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Comment: @JohnWilliams - agree. I am bit more distracted by the usage of English here -> `If not specified, the property must not be equal to false.`. If something is not specified how can it have any value by any means.